# Integer ordered pairs $(x,y)$ for which $x^2-y!$.....

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

[1] Total no. of Integer ordered pairs $(x,y)$ for which $x^2-y! = 2001$

[2] Total no. of Integer ordered pairs $(x,y)$ for which $x^2-y! = 2013$

My Try:: (1) $x^2-y! = 2001\Rightarrow x^2 = 2001+y!$

We Know that $y!$ end with $0, 1,2,4,6$ and last digit of $x^2$ is $0,1,4,5,6,9$

But I Did Not understand How can I proceed further

Help Required,

Thanks

Comment: You did remainder on dividing by ten.  Try remainders on dividing by some other numbers.

Comment: There are very few factorials that do not end in $0$, so you might treat those as special cases.  You only have four numbers to check in each problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** 2001 (and 2013) is a multiple of 3, but not 9.

**Hint:** There are no squares that are multiples of 3 but not 9.

**Hint:** There are finitely many factorials that are multiples of 3, but not 9.

Hence, you only need to check finitely many cases. In particular, you only need to check when $y = $(fill in the blank).

Answer (score 2):

As Calvin answered the first one, here is a hint for the other:

$$2013 \equiv 5  \pmod 8$$

If $x$ is odd, then $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$.

When $y \geq \cdots$ you know $8 \mid y!$.

Comment: I didn't answer the second one because it is the same as the first. 203 is a multiple if 3, but not 9.

Comment: @CalvinLin wow I missed the obvious :)

Comment: (Sorry for the typos in the comment) In general, questions of this form can be approached in a similar way, by looking at the (smallest) prime of odd power, and hence having finitely many cases. If the integer is a square, then I don't immediately know what to do, and any quadratic residue arguments like yours won't work either.

Answer (score 2):

We'll check $\left[1\right]$.

$x^{2} \geq 2002\quad$. Then, $x > 44.\quad$ Let's $x = 44 + \delta.\quad$. $\delta > 0.\quad$ Then

$$
\delta^{2} + 88\delta + y! - 65 = 0\,,
\quad
\delta_{\pm} = -44 \pm \sqrt{2001 - y!} < 0\ \mbox{for any}\quad y\ \ni y! \leq 2001
$$

$\color{#ff0000}{\large\mbox{Then,}\quad\color{#0000ff}{\left[1\right]\quad\mbox{is false.}}}$

Answer (score 0):

I will answer only the second equation and I will not use the known “modulo”, namely $\pmod{5}$, $\pmod{8}$, and $\pmod{9}$.

Since we know that $13^{3}-13^{2}=2028$ and $2028-13=2015$, then $2013\equiv11\equiv-2\pmod{13}$.

However, we know that $-2$ is only a quadratic residue to prime numbers $p\equiv 1,3\pmod{8}$, hence $x^{2}\equiv-2\equiv11\pmod{13}$ is not solvable, and thus $x^{2}-y!=2013$ does not have solutions when $y\geq12$.

Now, we need to only check the values of $y\leq11$ to see if are there any positive integer solutions and by brute force, it turns out there is none, and as a result, $x^{2}-y!=2013$ does not have any solutions where $x, y \in \mathsf{Z}^{+}$.