# Integer ordered pairs (x,y) satisfying $x^2 - y! = N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This question arose by looking at a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511723/integer-ordered-pairs-x-y-for-which-x2-y/511828?noredirect=1#comment1098250_511828), which has $N = 2001, 2013$. In it, my solution was that since we have a prime $p$ (in this case 3) which divides $N$ but $p^2$ doesn't, hence we merely need to consider the finitely many cases when $y < 2p$.

This argument easily extends to cases where $N$ has a prime power with an odd exponent, which leaves the cases where $N$ is a perfect square. I don't know how to approach this case, does anyone know how to solve

$$x^2 -n^2 = y!?$$

Are there finitely many solutions for each $n$?

Note: I believe that arguments by quadratic residues would not work.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question but every $n!$ can be put in the form of $n!= a^2-b^2=(a-b)*(a+b)$. It's clear that every factorial (larger than some small number) can have more than one factorisation.

Comment: @user25406 You changed the variables, which significantly changed the question. $\quad$ Note that $N = n^2$ is a given value, and $y!$ is the variable. So, how do you know that there is some $y!$ has a factorization into $(x-n)(x+n)$ for the specific value of $n$?

Comment: Well, we know that $6!=27^2-3^2$, $8!=201^2-9^2$...if we are talking about the same thing, then the solutions I wrote down are easily generated.

Comment: @user25406 (We're not talking about the same thing because you changed what was fixed and what was variable, but don't seem to be understanding that.) Specifically, take $N = 1$. Can you find all the solutions to $x^2 - y! = 1$? If so, please list them all out. (There are solutions like $4!+1 = 5^2$ with correspdonding $5^2 -1 = (5-1)(5+1) = 4 \times 6 = 4!$.)

Comment: I can only find the solutions if they exist. if they exist the solutions to $y!+1=x^2$ can be found by solving the following quadratic equation: $k^2 + 2k - n!=0$. The solutions for $4!,5!,7!$ can be found using the simple quadratic.  I have no way of finding solutions involving very large factorials because I don't code.

Comment: @user25406 What do you mean by "if they exist"? Are you saying that you can merely manually "check specific cases of $y$"? Or "If we know that a solution exists and we give you $x$ (or $y$), then you can find the other value?  $\quad$ Put another way, the question is to find all such $(x,y)$, as opposed to finding all such $(y, N)$.

Comment: Exactly. You can convince yourself by working the case for $4!$ by solving $k^2 + 2k -4!=0$ and that of $5!$ and $7!$.  
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697074/is-this-formulation-of-the-brocard-problem-better-suited-to-tackle-the-problem-o

Comment: @user25406 To be clear, you are not understanding what the question is asking for. I want all values of $(x,y)$ for a fixed $N$. $\quad$ You are saying "If you give me any $y$ that HAS a solution, I can find $x$". That can be easily done like you pointed out, and it's not what the problem is asking for. The question is asking how we can find all $y$ that has a solution to a given $N$.  $\quad$ At this point, I'm unable to get this through to you and there isn't much more I can say, so I'm stepping away from this exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Even for $n=1,$ which is called Brocard's problem, it is an open question whether this equation has finitely many solutions. There is extensive literature devoted to equation of the type $P(x)=m!.$ I would recommend to look at the article of [Berend and Armes](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2006-358-04/S0002-9947-05-03780-3/S0002-9947-05-03780-3.pdf)

where they treat a few important special cases.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at $n=1$ and could get nowhere, no matter what I tried to do. Good to know that it's an open question lol.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad to save you some time :)